# JavaScript Security Concerns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an eCommerce application that's using quite a bit of JavaScript and jQuery.  Everything is checked server-side before anything is processed, but there has been a lot of news lately regarding web-based break-ins via JavaScript.  I was just wondering what type of things I can do to reduce this threat and if there were any good websites that had information on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Security can't be compromised unless javascript manipulates something AND it is then sent back to your server/database.  If it is simply javascript then it cannot harm your server.

Comment: @thepristinedesign: Really? Then what is a Cross Site Scripting attack?

Comment: Validate everything server-side, basicaly make sure nothing important can be intercept and modify.

Comment: @CraigStuntz XSS is when someone put malicious js code on your site

Comment: and what about hijacking cookies? or polluting global namespace? or XSS as pointed by @craig? Or I open your site and some how modify the js and send final price for a galaxy sII to 10US$ and send to your server?

Comment: @Alexcp, validating server side is not enough. And no, that is *not* what XSS means, necessarily; it's only one flavor of XSS. If I can get banksite.com to display content from evilsite.com in an iframe, then I can rob its users without ever touching the server. There are no simple answers here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @CraigStuntz This is exactly what I said. In order to display an iframe on the website you have to inject js code somewhere...

Comment: @Alexcp: But the malicious code doesn't have to be "on your site". If you have a URL injection vulnerability, that's just as bad. What I'm saying is that even if the server itself is 100% secure (if only!) you can still have a *JavaScript-only* flaw which lets the bad guys rob your users.

Comment: From what I understand (I am a somewhat new developer) Javascript is CLIENT side.  Yes, if your javascript validates a form, then it gets sent to the server then its a problem.  But if you simply have javascript manipulating visuals on the site then you don't have to worry.  A hacker can only manipulate _their_ version of looking at your site (and so can any competent person using firebug)...

Comment: @thepristinedesign, that is **entirely wrong.** Dangerously so, in fact. Google "XSS URL injection."

Comment: I apologize for my naivety.  I'll definitely look into XSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good link to read about XSS:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Basically, what a "hacker" is trying to do when they use XSS is get the user to think your site is asking them for something secure, when really the "hacker" is asking (by injecting script into your site) and is sending that data to somewhere unsecure. Comes in many flavors.

The usual prevention measures are to sanitize you data (so a "hacker" can't inject scripts via data entry). Basically, anything that is dynamically created or comes from users (even your own content people) should be encoded so that script, etc cannot be executed.

Many people seem confused about the goals of XSS. If you think that your server and the data on it are the only thing to protect, you are wrong. XSS is often directed at the user, rather than the server, the "hacker" is trying to steal from the user, not the server (or it's owners). Stealing from the user may in turn result in stealing from the server (got the users credentials, now go buy stuff impersonating the user).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Google Gruyere](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/). It's a tutorial on a fake web site with a lot of security holes that you can exploit in order to better understand common security problems in web applications. It goes over XSS and other problems that can occur in JavaScript, as well as some server-side problems.